# Perform setting operations in flutter (scanner code )

Tags: flutter

I want when the user click on beep button in setting page "it will Allow beep sound on scan complete" and "when the user click on Vibrate "it allow vibrate on scan" ,when the user click on Web ,the web will true and the scan generated result will automatically that generated link.

```
// perform on the below given page

class _ScannerPageState extends State<ScannerPage> {
  String scanResult = "";
  bool _vibrateChecked = true;
  // final vibrateChecked = Provider.of<AppSettings>(context as BuildContext).vibrateChecked;
  Future<void> scanQR() async {

    try {
      final scanResult = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
        '#ff6666',
        'Cancel',
        true,
        ScanMode.BARCODE,

      );

      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        this.scanResult = scanResult;
      });
    // log('de_alam scanner $scanResult');
    if(scanResult=="-1"){

      return;
    }

      if (scanResult.isNotEmpty) {
        if (_vibrateChecked) {
          Vibration.vibrate(duration: 500);
        }
        Navigator.push( context as BuildContext,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ResultPage(scanResult: scanResult, vibrateChecked: _vibrateChecked ),
          ),
        );
      }

    } on PlatformException {
      setState(() {
        this.scanResult = "Failed to get platform version";

        // else {
        // Navigate back to the home page when scan is canceled
        // Navigator.pop(context);
        // }
      });

    }
  }
```